# How to test OnErrorResume functionality in reactive programming

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I have the below service code

```
Mono<Student> responseDataMono = (Mono<Student>)myWebClient
                .getResponse("url");

        return responseDataMono
                .onErrorResume(ex -> {
                  
                    if (null!=ex && null!= ex.getMessage() && ex.getMessage().contains("404")) {
                        // not found logic
                        
                    } else if(null!=ex && null!= ex.getMessage() && ex.getMessage().contains("400")){
                        //timeout logic
                        
                    }else if(ex instanceof io.netty.handler.timeout.TimeoutException){
                        //bad request logic
                        
                    }else{
                        // internal servicer error logic
                        
                    }
                    return Mono.empty();
                }).map(resp-> resp);
```

so based on the error type i have added my logic. It is working fine. i.e) while calling API it is executing corresponding if block based on the logic added.
Now i want to add junit for that. This is my junit code

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest{
    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myServiceMock;

    @Mock
    private MyWebClient myWebClient;

   public void TestErrorCode(){

      doThrow((new WebClientResponseException(400,"Bad Request",null,null,null)))
                .when(myWebClient)
                .getResponse(any());
     Assert.assertThrows(WebClientResponseException.class, () -> {
            Mono<Student> student= 
            myServiceMock.myServiceMethod();
        });
      
   }

}
```

I tried the above method assuming that will throw web client exception while calling webclient so that my service will also throw error and my onErrorResume code will execute.

but what is happening is while calling the webclient it is throwing error which is correct but the responsedataMono is null. So it is not proceeding further.

Can anyone please guide how to cover these scenarios in recative.

Comment: ex can never be null, as reactive datatypes like `Mono` and `Flux` do not allow null values

Answer (score 2):

in order to use the `error` channel of a Mono, you need to wrap the exception into a mono, not directly throw it. In other words, your mocking should look like this:

```
doReturn(Mono.error(() -> new WebClientResponseException(400, "Bad Request", null, null, null)))
    .when(myWebClient)
    .getResponse(any());
```

Now the code will reach the `onErrorResume` block. In this block, you can recover from the error and return a default `student` (wrapped in a mono) if you want, or the code flow reaches the end of the block and it will return a `Mono.empty()`.

If you want to test it, there are a few different ways, for example you can use a StepVerifier: https://www.baeldung.com/reactive-streams-step-verifier-test-publisher

A less flexible (but simpler) alternative is to block the result for assertions:

```
@Test
void test() {
    MyWebClient myWebClient = mock(MyWebClient.class);
    doReturn(Mono.error(() -> new WebClientResponseException(400, "Bad Request", null, null, null)))
            .when(myWebClient)
            .getResponse(any());

    Mono<Student> responseDataMono = (Mono<Student>) myWebClient
            .getResponse("url");

    var testedFlow = responseDataMono
            .onErrorResume(ex -> {
                if (null != ex && null != ex.getMessage() && ex.getMessage().contains("404")) {
                    System.out.println("not found!");
                    // not found logic
                } else if (null != ex && null != ex.getMessage() && ex.getMessage().contains("400")) {
                    System.out.println("client error!");
                    //timeout logic
                } else if (ex instanceof TimeoutException) {
                    //bad request logic
                } else {
                    // internal servicer error logic
                }
                return Mono.empty();
            }).map(resp -> resp);

    assertThat(testedFlow.blockOptional()).isEmpty();
}
```

---

Ps: there are better ways of handling errors with Mono's API. For example you can break the if-else logic like this:

```
responseDataMono
    .onErrorResume(err -> err.getMessage().contains("404"), err -> {
        // not found logic
        return Mono.empty();
    })
    .onErrorResume(err -> err.getMessage().contains("400"), err -> {
        // bad request logic
        return Mono.empty();
    })
    .onErrorResume(TimeoutException.class, err -> {
        // not found logic
        return Mono.empty();
    })
    .onErrorResume(ex -> {
        // internal servicer error logic
        return Mono.empty();
    }).map(resp -> resp);
```

Additionally, I wouldn't relly on the error message containing a string, what if the error is something like "account with id=12400 was not found" - is this a 400 error or a 404? Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
responseDataMono
    .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.NotFound.class, err -> {
        // not found logic
        return Mono.empty();
    })
    .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.BadRequest.class, err -> {
        // bad request logic
        return Mono.empty();
    })
    // ... etc
    .map(resp -> resp);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems u have wrong brackets order, 'getResponse' should be inside of 'when' brackets

```
doThrow((new WebClientResponseException(400,"Bad Request",null,null,null)))
                .when(myWebClient.getResponse(any()));
```